# how to solve Reduce the impact of third-party code in pagespeed insights

Tags: performance, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

I have developed my website with html,css,and javascript. I am trying to improve the pagespeed scores. i have tried may methods to solve this **Reduce the impact of third-party code** issue, but its not working.the third party scripts are **google tag manager** and **google analytics** scripts only

Answer (score 0):

There are a few resources on web.dev for improving third party performance:

- https://web.dev/tag-best-practices/
- https://web.dev/third-party-javascript/
- https://web.dev/controlling-third-party-scripts/